# Pytest: skip printout of passed test, get summary of result

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to setup continues integration and I would like the pytest printout to skip passed test, my current command is:

```
pytest -vv -x -rf
```

And the current printout is:

```
PS C:\repository\Backend> pytest -vv -x -rf
==================================================== test session starts =====================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- C:\Python\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\repository\Backend
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 66 items

tests/test_endpoints.py::test_if_columns_match PASSED                                                                   [  1%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search PASSED                                                                             [  3%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search_limit PASSED                                                                       [  4%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search_with_no_limit PASSED                                                               [  6%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search_orderby PASSED                                                                     [  7%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search_with_multiple_params PASSED                                                        [  9%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search_with_invalid_column PASSED                                                         [ 10%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_read PASSED                                                                               [ 12%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_read_empty PASSED                                                                         [ 13%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_read_bad_id PASSED                                                                        [ 15%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_insert PASSED                                                                             [ 16%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_search_sql_injection PASSED                                                               [ 18%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_insert_empty PASSED                                                                       [ 19%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_update PASSED                                                                             [ 21%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_update_empty_dict PASSED                                                                  [ 22%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_update_empty_params PASSED                                                                [ 24%] 
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_update_sql_injection PASSED                                                               [ 25%] 
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_delete PASSED                                                                             [ 27%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_delete_twice PASSED                                                                       [ 28%]
tests/test_endpoints.py::test_delete_empty PASSED                                                                       [ 30%] 
tests/test_scripts.py::test_script_exist PASSED                                                                         [ 31%] 
tests/test_scripts.py::test_if_columns_match PASSED                                                                     [ 33%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_string_eq PASSED                                                                            [ 34%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_string_in PASSED                                                                            [ 36%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_string_sw PASSED                                                                            [ 37%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_float_eq PASSED                                                                             [ 39%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_float_gr PASSED                                                                             [ 40%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_float_lt PASSED                                                                             [ 42%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_float_ge PASSED                                                                             [ 43%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_float_le PASSED                                                                             [ 45%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_integer_eq PASSED                                                                           [ 46%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_integer_gr PASSED                                                                           [ 48%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_integer_lt PASSED                                                                           [ 50%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_integer_ge PASSED                                                                           [ 51%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_integer_le PASSED                                                                           [ 53%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_date_eq PASSED                                                                              [ 54%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_date_gr PASSED                                                                              [ 56%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_date_lt PASSED                                                                              [ 57%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_date_ge PASSED                                                                              [ 59%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_date_le PASSED                                                                              [ 60%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_multiple_operators_1 PASSED                                                                 [ 62%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_multiple_operators_2 PASSED                                                                 [ 63%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_string_eq PASSED                                                                    [ 65%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_string_in PASSED                                                                    [ 66%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_string_sw PASSED                                                                    [ 68%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_float_eq PASSED                                                                     [ 69%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_float_gr PASSED                                                                     [ 71%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_float_lt PASSED                                                                     [ 72%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_float_ge PASSED                                                                     [ 74%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_float_le PASSED                                                                     [ 75%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_integer_eq PASSED                                                                   [ 77%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_integer_gr PASSED                                                                   [ 78%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_integer_lt PASSED                                                                   [ 80%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_integer_ge PASSED                                                                   [ 81%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_integer_le PASSED                                                                   [ 83%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_date_eq PASSED                                                                      [ 84%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_date_gr PASSED                                                                      [ 86%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_date_lt PASSED                                                                      [ 87%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_date_ge PASSED                                                                      [ 89%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_date_le PASSED                                                                      [ 90%]
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_multiple_operators_1 PASSED                                                         [ 92%] 
tests/test_scripts.py::test_invalid_multiple_operators_2 PASSED                                                         [ 93%] 
tests/scripts/test_script.py::test_blank_filter PASSED                                                                  [ 95%] 
tests/scripts/test_script.py::test_empty_result PASSED                                                                  [ 96%] 
tests/scripts/test_script.py::test_basic_filter PASSED                                                                  [ 98%] 
tests/scripts/test_script.py::test_complex_filter PASSED                                                                [100%] 

==================================================== 66 passed in 15.68s ===================================================== 
PS C:\repository\Backend>
```

I currently save this result as github PR comment, which can be quite long with more tests, is it possible to make it shorter with just a summary of the how many passed and how many failed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-q` or `--quiet` option when running tests

Comment: that doesn't seem to be an option for pytest

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer -q is a definitely pytest verbosity control option I am using on my CI server, use --help to check it out or run tests with -q